# Truffle, getPastEvents synchronously

Tags: events, truffle-test

I try to check that a total of 4 events have been emitted by  my contract instance. Next code will fail in the `assert.equal` line since getPastEvents will process the events in a callback and so the assert will be executed before the callback being able to process (and count) the events.

```
// NOTE: Error control removed for clarity.
it("SHOULD FETCH 4 EVENTS", async () => {                                                                     
  const EXPECTED_EVENT_COUNT = 4;                                                                             
  var TOTAL_COUNT = 0;                                                                                              
  myContractInstance.getPastEvents(
      'MyTestedEvent',
      { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' },
      function(error, result) { 
        TOTAL_COUNT++; 
      }
  );
  assert.equal(TOTAL_COUNT, EXPECTED_EVENT_COUNT, "");
})
```

Is there any trick to make the `assert.equal` line wait in a loop until a condition is met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! No need to use a callback to count for total number of event.

```
it("SHOULD FETCH 4 EVENTS", async () => {                                                                     
  const EXPECTED_EVENT_COUNT = 4;                                                                             
  const options = { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' }

  const eventList = await 
     myContractInstance.getPastEvents('MyTestedEvent',options);
  assert.equal(eventList.lenght, EXPECTED_EVENT_COUNT, "");
})
```

As adapted from: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/next/packages/truffle-contract/test/events.js#L134-L148

Comment: Do know though, that on the mainnet fetching from block `0`, will bring you much inconsistency and sorrow, so you would prefer to use a much closer blocknumber, for example the contract whose events you are trying to fetch's deployment blocknumber.